# how to group my query result by date in php email

Tags: php, mysql

I am sending a **MySQL** query result in **PHP** email. There are two fields, `date` and `emailtext`. There is also a date part in the `emailtext`, so basically it looks like this:

```
Date               emailtext
02/21/2017         02-21-2017-this is today's price
02/22/2017         02-22-2017-this is today's price
```

From my **PHP** email I am able to display each row from the `emailtext` like this (date is not included):

```
`02-21-2017-this` is today's `price`
`02-22-2017-this` is today's `price`
```

my goal is to display the `emailtext` group by date like this:

```
02/21/2017  

`02-21-2017-this` is today's `price 1`
`02-21-2017-this` is today's `price 2`

02/22/2017  

`02-22-2017-this` is today's `price 1`
`02-22-2017-this` is today's `price 2`
```

Is there any way I can achieve this, any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you reformat your question? It's confusing. I'm not sure what you want to achieve.